# How to deallocate memory for const std::vector<unsigned char>

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector

I am using one library api which returns  const std::vector . Below is the code

```
const std::vector<unsigned char> myvar = getData();
```

Now i have cleanup memory for myvar. How to do this with c++.

I am trying something like

```
std::for_each(myvar.begin(), myvar.end(), [&](unsigned char mychar)
{
    cout<<mychar<<",";


    delete &mychar;

});
```

But failing with the heap curruption.

Thanks for the input.

Comment: You don't have to clean up after `std::vector`. That's half the point.

Comment: std::vector automatically cleans up in its destructor, so when it goes out of scope, all the memory will be freed.  if you want to free elements before destruction, you can call *erase* or *resize*.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization

Comment: *"Now I have cleanup memory for `myvar`. How to do this with C++"* - Not at all (well, not yourself at least), it's a `std::vector` exhibiting C++'s standard way of managing resources.

Comment: You are trying to delete a pointer to a local variable ( the lambda argument in this case ). you can only call delete on heap-allocated objects.

Answer (score 5):

STL uses [RAII idiom,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), it allocates memory when necessary and deallocate automatically.

You don't need to manually deallcoate `myvar`, just let `myvar` go out of scope, all memory will be deallocate automatically.

```
// new scope, maybe function, maybe if/while scope: 
{
    const std::vector<unsigned char> myvar = getData();
}
// myvar will be deallocated
```

Note, always call `new/delete`, `new [] / delete[]` in pair, you didn't call new for any `myvar` member, you don't need call `delete` at all.

Comment: True, but is there any possibilty that getData() is allocating memory for myvar and i should responsible to cleanup this. Because my program is showing huge memory leak.

Comment: @user1648040 you could have a memory leak in `getData()` itself. Difficult to know without seeing some code.

Comment: @user1648040, There's no way a vector of characters would cause that in itself, what with RAII.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to manually delete the contents of that vector. The vector's destructor will take care of all necessary memory allocation, and will be called when the object goes out of scope. For example,

```
{

  const std::vector<unsigned char> v('a', 1000); // size 1000 vector

} // v's destructor called here.
```

This is one of the many reasons to use standard library types. Have a look at the not very aptly named [resource acquisition is initialization, or RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

Answer (score 2):

```
void myFunc()
{
    const std::vector<unsigned char> myvar = getData();

} // <----- Like this
```

Vector will take care of deallocating its own contents, when it is destroyed at the end of its containing scope. Remember, you don't need to `delete`, unless you `new`.

Comment: Or, sadly, unless someone else `new`s and passes ownership off to you. In that case, stick what's given into a smart pointer :)